# Jackson to deserialize wrapper class with array of primitive types

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class as follows, wrapping array of bytes:

```
public final class Plan {
  private byte[] bytes;
  private int peekIdx;

  public Plan(byte[] bytes, int peekIdx) {
      this.bytes = bytes;
      this.peekIdx = peekIdx;
  }

  public Plan(byte[] bytes) {
      this(bytes, 0);
  }

  //bunch more methods
}
```

This is contained in other objects as

```
public final class Agent {
     private Plan plan;
     //bunch more properties...
}
```

Now I want to deserialize a JSON like

```
{"plan": [0, 1, 2]}
```

as an Agent. However I can't figure out how to annotate `Plan` to achieve this. If it was just `byte[]` there wouldn't be an issue as this would correspond directly to a named property in Agent that can be put as `@JsonProperty("plan")`, but I somehow need to tell Jackson how to wrap the array in a `Plan` object. How to achieve this? Does it really require a custom serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `@JsonValue` on the `bytes`-getter in the `Plan` class. It will tell Jackson that the class should be serialized using only that value. Also, a creator needs to be specified as below.

Like this:

```
class Plan {


  // ...

  @JsonCreator
  public Plan(byte[] bytes) {
    this(bytes, 0);
  }

  @JsonValue
  public byte[] getBytes() {
      return bytes;
  }

  // ...

}
```

Comment: I've added a hint that the constructor is also needed. Thank you! `@JsonValue` was indeed what I was missing.

Comment: Ah, yes. The `@JsonCreator` is needed for deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your second constructor with `@JsonCreator`, specifying the name of the JSON field to be sent as the `byte` array parameter:

```
@JsonCreator
public Plan(@JsonProperty("plan") byte[] bytes) {
    this(bytes, 0);
}
```

This tells Jackson to use this constructor, sending to it the value of the `plan` field of the JSON object.

Comment: something about this does not seem to work - I'm getting `No serializer found for class ch.ethz.systems.nqsim.Plan and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer`

Comment: @MichelMüller Worked in my tests. Do you have proper beans with getters and setters?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid setters here, so that's probably the issue.